# Property 'X' with type 'Y' cannot override a property with type 'Z'

Tags: swift

**My code reported the following error:**

> Property 'children' with type '[BottomTabChildren]' cannot override a
>   property with type '[UIViewController]'.

**My error code:**

```
var children = [BottomTabChildren]()
```

**Related code:**

```
 struct BottomTabChildren: HandyJSON {

    var schema_href: String = "" // sslocal://webview?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.guanfumuseum.org.cn%2F

    var type: String = "" // href

    var name: String = ""

    var value: String = "" // http://www.guanfumuseum.org.cn/
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, edit the title and body of your question with a better description of what you are trying to do and when are you getting this error. Check the "How do I ask a good question?" in the Help Center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

In the `super` class, there is a property named `children` of type `[UIViewController]` so you shouldn't use the same name to declare another type. Rename `[BottomTabChildren]` property to something as,

```
var tabChildren = [BottomTabChildren]()
```